# Parallelize data processing

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, julia

I have a large matrix `data` that I want to "organize" in a certain way. The matrix has 5 columns and about 2 million rows. The first 4 columns are characteristics of each observation (these are integers) and the last column is the outcome variable I'm interested in (this contains real numbers). I want to organize this matrix in an Array of Arrays. Since `data` is very large, I'm trying to parallelize this operation:

```
addprocs(3)

@everywhere data = readcsv("datalocation", Int)

@everywhere const Z = 65
@everywhere const z = 16
@everywhere const Y = 16
@everywhere const y = 10

@everywhere const arr = Array{Vector}(Z-z+1,Y-y+1,Z-z+1,Y-y+1)

@parallel (vcat) for a1 in z:Z, e1 in y:Y, a2 in z:Z, e2 in y:Y
    arr[a1-z+1,e1-y+1,a2-z+1,e2-y+1] = data[(data[:,1].==a1) & (data[:,2].==e1) & (data[:,3].==a2) & (data[:,4].==e2), end]
end
```

However I get an error when I try to run the for loop:

```
Error: syntax: invalid assignment location
```

After the loop is finished, I would like to have `arr` available to all processors. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The input matrix `data` looks like this (rows in no particular order):

```
16   10   16   10   100
16   10   16   11   200
20   12   21   13   500
16   10   16   10   300
20   12   21   13   500
```

Notice that some rows can be repeated, and some others will have the same "key" but a different fifth column.

The output I want looks like this (notice how I'm using the dimensions of `arr` as "keys" for a "dictionary":

```
arr[16-z+1, 10-y+1, 16-z+1, 10-y+1] = [100, 300]
arr[16-z+1, 10-y+1, 16-z+1, 11-y+1] = [200]
arr[20-z+1, 12-y+1, 21-z+1, 13-y+1] = [500, 500]
```

That is, the element of `arr` at index `(16-z+1, 10-y+1, 16-z+1, 10-y+1)` is the vector `[100, 300]`. I don't care about the ordering of the rows or the ordering of the last column of vectors.

Comment: Why are you using (vcat)? That will cat together all of the `arr[a1-z+1,e1-y+1,a2-z+1,e2-y+1] `, but isn't the solution `arr`, so you don't need to be using the return values? I think you need to make `arr` a shared or distributed array to make this work, or you drop the assignment and make arr from the loop.

Comment: I realized I misinterpreted your question - I thought you were trying to split your data up amongst workers, but actually, you're just using the workers to organize the data on the main process.

Comment: @michael thanks for the great effort anyways.

Comment: My general recommendation would be to perhaps consider partitioning all the combinations in your loop indices over the different workers, then have each worker do the sorting just over its given indices, and then recombine the results afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?  I tried to simulate your data by repeating the snippet that you gave of it 1000 times.  It's not as elegant as I would have wanted and in particular, I couldn't quite get the `remotecall_fetch()` working like I wanted (even when wrapping it with `@async`) so I had to split the calling and the fetching into two steps.  Let me know though how this seems.

```
addprocs(n)

@everywhere begin
    if myid() != 1
        multiplier = 10^3;
        Data = readdlm("/path/to/Input.txt")
        global data = kron(Data,ones(multiplier));
        println(size(data))
    end
end

@everywhere begin
    function Select_Data(a1, e1, a2, e2, data=data)
        return data[(data[:,1].==a1) & (data[:,2].==e1) & (data[:,3].==a2) & (data[:,4].==e2), end]
    end
end

n_workers = nworkers()
function next_pid(pid, n_workers)
    if pid <= n_workers
        return pid + 1
    else
        return 2
    end
end

const arr = Array{Any}(Z-z+1,Y-y+1,Z-z+1,Y-y+1);
println("Beginning Processing Work")
@sync begin
    pid = 2
    for a1 in z:Z, e1 in y:Y, a2 in z:Z, e2 in y:Y
        pid = next_pid(pid, n_workers)
        arr[a1-z+1,e1-y+1,a2-z+1,e2-y+1] = remotecall(pid, Select_Data, a1, e1, a2, e2)
    end
end
println("Retrieving Completed Jobs")
@sync begin
    pid = 2
    for a1 in z:Z, e1 in y:Y, a2 in z:Z, e2 in y:Y
        arr[a1-z+1,e1-y+1,a2-z+1,e2-y+1] = fetch(arr[a1-z+1,e1-y+1,a2-z+1,e2-y+1])
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm trying that now with my real data. I suppose `arr` has to be `Array{Any}` because `remotecall` does not return `Vector`. Are there any penalties associated with this?

Comment: @amrods yeah, there probably are.  But I couldn't figure out why when I tried using `remotecall_fetch()` it only had work being done on one  process.  Maybe Chris might have ideas on how to fix that aspect.

Comment: @amrods You could also do two arrays.  One for the `arr1` which is type any, and then `arr2` which is your desired type and which fetches from `arr1`.  I also wasn't totally certain as to exactly what you wanted in your end result (e.g. what was going on with that `vcat` you were using).  But, if this works in principal, then even if it doesn't do exactly what you want, it would hopefully be adaptable.

Comment: Also, I noticed that when retrieving the jobs, you do not iterate on the `pid`, why is that?

Comment: @amrods I don't think this is necessary to specify the `pid` when fetching.  The `remotecall-ref` type object already has this info stored in it, I'm pretty sure.  (feel free to double check your results though and/or try it otherwise to make sure).

Comment: just getting back to you, this reduces in half the time time it takes to complete the operation, from 3911.18 seconds to 2101.05 seconds

Comment: @amrods Ok, well, I'd say that's at least a decent victory.  To be honest, given the challenges that both I (and apparently Chris) faced, I'm delighted it worked at all.  It is relatively uncommon for total job time to decrease exactly as much as adding more processors might suggest.

Comment: @amrods How many cores are you running?  Have you looked at their utilization rates?  Frequently, with hyper-threaded cores, you can efficiently run two jobs on each core.

Comment: True, with hyper threading I have 4 procs. Just to check, I can add then 3 more procs with `addprocs(3)`, right? I can also move this job to my university cluster in which case I have thousands, but I understand there is tradeoff in using many cores.

Comment: @amrods Yeah, I think in your case it's probably safe to use `addprocs(4)`.  At times, "best practices" will say to keep a whole proc free just to be the controller, but that is often overkill.  The script I wrote only has the workers doing work, not the controller.  re: moving to cluster - I don't think that would be a big problem.  Again, doubling the cores won't necessarily half your compute time, but for something like this it should still scale moderately linearly, even if the |slope| is < 1.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I initially misinterpreted your question.  I had thought that you were trying to split the data amongst your workers, but I now see that isn't quite what you were after.  I wrote up some simplified examples of ways that can be accomplished.  I'll leave them up as a response in case anyone in the future finds them useful.

Get started:

```
writedlm("path/to/data.csv", rand(100,10), ',')
addprocs(4)
```

Option 1:

```
function sendto(p::Int; args...)
    for (nm, val) in args
        @spawnat(p, eval(Main, Expr(:(=), nm, val)))
    end
end

Data = readcsv("/path/to/data.csv")

for (idx, pid) in enumerate(workers())
    Start = (idx-1)*25 + 1
    End = Start + 24
    sendto(pid, Data = Data[Start:End,])
end
```

Option 2:

```
@everywhere begin
    if myid() != 1
        Start = (myid()-2)*25 + 1
        End = Start + 24
        println(Start)
        println(End)
        Data = readcsv("path/to/data.csv")[Start:End,:]
    end
end

# verify everything looks right for what got sent
@everywhere if myid()!= 1 println(typeof(Data)) end
@everywhere if myid()!= 1 println(size(Data)) end
```

Option 3:

```
for (idx, pid) in enumerate(workers())
    Start = (idx-1)*25 + 1
    End = Start + 24
    sendto(pid, Start = Start, End = End)
end

@everywhere if myid()!= 1 Data = readcsv("path/to/data.csv")[Start:End,:] end
```

Comment: @amrods.  It's a bit tricky, but need not be too bad.  I updated with a couple examples to give you a starter.